# Intersection of two arrays

Tags: algorithms, arrays

As part of a project i'm doing I have been looking for a way to find common values between 2 arrays including duplicates.
For example;

A = [2, 2, 3, 5]
B = [2, 2, 5]
would return the array;

Common values = [2, 2, 5]

I have attempted using sets, and the intersection function, but neither gave duplicates

Any help appreciated

Comment: What would be the expected output if $A=[2,2]$ and $B=[2]$?

Comment: Coding questions are off-topic here. You may try [so]

Comment: (intersect `Counter`s)

Comment: Do you have an algorithm in mind?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-intersection-two-lists/

Comment: python-specific questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 4):

Python-specific questions are probably off-topic here, but this question can be seen as a language-agnostic algorithmic task: given two arrays $A$ and $B$, each representing a multi-set, return an array containing the elements in the multiset $C = A \cap B$.
Here an element $x$ that has multiplicity $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$, has multiplicity $\min\{a,b\}$ in $C$.

To solve this problem you can preliminary sort $A$ and $B$. Then, you can keep a pointer $p_A$ to some element of $A$ and a pointer $p_B$ to some element of $B$. Initially $p_A$ (resp. $p_B$) will point to the first element of  $A$ (resp. $B$).
I will use $A[p_A]$ (resp. $B[p_B]$) to denote the element of $A$ (resp. $B$) pointed by $p_A$ (resp. $p_B$). Also, it is convenient to assume that, whenever $p_A$ (resp. $p_B$) points past the end of $A$ (resp. $B$), $A[p_A]$ (resp. $B[p_B]$) has value $+\infty$.

Proceed similarly to the merge step of Mergesort:

- Initialize $C$ as an empty array.
- While ($p_A$ is not past the end of $A$) or ($p_B$ is not past the end of $B$)

  - If $A[p_A] = B[p_B]$:

    - Append $A[p_A]$ to $C$.
    - Advance $p_A$
    - Advance $p_B$.
  - Else if $A[p_A] > B[p_B]$:

    - Advance $p_B$
  - Else (in this case $A[p_A] < B[p_B]$):

    - Advance $p_A$

Answer (score 3):

While Steven's answer is correct, it runs in time $O(n \log n)$.  Here is a Pythonic way of doing it that uses dictionaries and runs in linear time.

```python
from collections import Counter

A = [2, 2, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6]
B = [2, 3, 4, 4]
CA = Counter(A)
CB = Counter(B)

solution = []
for e in CA:
    occurrences = min(CA[e], CB.get(e, 0))
    solution += [e]*occurrences
print(solution)
```

You can of course implement Counter yourself easily in other languages.

Comment: This runs in **expected** linear time.

Comment: @Steven Yes, I expect it runs in linear time!

Comment: you shouldnt provide a code in this site @PålGD

Comment: @monther there's nothing wrong with code and there's certainly not a rule against code on this site. While this isn't a _programming_ site, questions, and indeed answers, on algorithms are very much on topic. The language with which you communicate the algorithms is up to the author. Python is in many aspects close to pseudocode, which is why I often choose it.

Answer (score -4):

#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int n1,n2,n3,i,j,k,count=0;

int a[n1],b[n2],c[n3];

n1=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

n2=sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);

n3=sizeof(c)/sizeof(c[0]);

printf("Enter the size of each array\n");

scanf("%d %d %d",&n1,&n2,&n3);

printf("enter %d elements:\n",n1);

for(i = 0; i < n1; i++) {

```
 scanf("%d", &a[i]);
```

}printf("enter %d elements:\n",n2);

for(i = 0; i < n2; i++) {

```
 scanf("%d", &b[i]);
```

}printf("enter %d elements:\n",n3);

for(i = 0; i < n3; i++) {

```
 scanf("%d", &c[i]);
```

}printf("Intersection elements:\n");

for(i=0;i<n1;i++){

```
  for(j=0;j<n2;j++){

    if (a[i]==b[i]){

      for(k=0;k<n3;k++){

            if((a[i]==b[j])&&(b[j]==c[k]))

                    printf("%d\n",a[i]);

                    count++;

                }

                    
          }

      }

}
```

printf("No.of loops %d\n",count);

return 0;

}

Comment: We are looking for algorithms rather than code. Also, what is the time complexity of your algorithm?

Comment: *Review answer* to what question? And what, in turn, is yours?

Comment: (If I looked, I wouldn't see counting *loops*, but *trips*/*iterations*.)